# Getting a tooltip to work with an inverted axis

Tags: python, data-visualization, bokeh

Using Bokeh, I'm trying to create a chart that has an inverted Y-Axis AND a hover tooltip.

I know how to do each of those independently, but can't combine them.

I guess that specifying `y_range` with integers that bokeh can't relate to the `ColumnDataSource` that is used for plotting/tooltip is causing the problem. But how to solve it?

#### Normal axis, tooltip working

```
p = bk.figure(title='Non-Inverted Axis, Hover tool-tip', tools=TOOLS,
 plot_width=600, plot_height=300)
p.circle(y='x', x='y', source=source)
hover = p.select(dict(type=HoverTool))
hover.tooltips = [
    ("x", "@x"),
    ("y", "@y"),
]

bk.show(p)
```

[image]

#### Inverted Axis, no tooltips

```
p = bk.figure(title='Inverted Axis, no tool-tip', tools=TOOLS,
 plot_width=600, plot_height=300, y_range=(10,0))
p.circle(y='x', x='y', source=source)
hover = p.select(dict(type=HoverTool))
hover.tooltips = [
    ("x", "@x"),
    ("y", "@y"),
]

bk.show(p)
```

[image]

[Here's a notebook](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/knightofni/f6a6538935094a4371ae) with the full code used to generate the plots.

How can I get an inverted axis working with tooltips? Maybe it's not possible?

Comment: This seems like a bug, I encourage you to post this information to the Bokeh GitHub issue tracker: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues

Comment: done, thanks ! https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/2064